# Connecting MYSQL database to Public_HTML PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

So I'm trying my hand in constructing a small CMS for my workplace. Our current site is hosted via hostGator, so I used cpanel to create a new mysql database and a simple 'users' table to store usernames and passwords.

How would I go about opening a connection from a php file, which will be the root of a subdomain located on the same server, to the database I've created?

I guess I'm mainly confused about what a proper path ($host ?) from the php file should look like?

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="energyto_user"; // Mysql username
$password="*****"; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="users"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or
die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and
password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword");
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: For the love of hot sauce, please hide your passwords in your code/question.

Comment: Hm? Is your code working or not? It seems like it should be working, and in case your host isn't `localhost` then you'll have to ask your hosting provider for what it is, we can't guess. Also, please avoid `mysql_*` functions, they are being deprecated and won't be available in future PHP versions. Read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further details... And: **don't** store the password in session, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, sigh, definitely shouldn't be storing passwords in the php. What do you recommend doing to retrieve it externally? And I'm getting a connection now, but it's not finding the database? I renamed it to energyto_test, and the username and password should be correct, but it's simply giving me a 'cannot connect to database' error.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really think you will have much trouble doing this.. just include the relative address of this php configuration file in all the pages and it should ideally work provided both the files are in the same folder and there is NO ".htaccess" file blocking connection.

The best way I normally recommend people to do is to define classes.. if this is just a start of your project will highly recommend using classes and define database classes and use objects of those classes.. its secure and makes it easier once you get used it...

cheers..

Answer (score -1):

I think your db name should be `energyto_test`

Comment: Perhaps your name should be David Blaine? :)

Comment: Before being so ironic you should think a little bit about what I've wrote.. Generally, hosting providers automatically creates your database users and sets the database name like `HostUsername_DATABASE-USER` and `HostUsername_YOUR-CHOSEN-DATABASE-NAME`. In this case, I think that the HostUsername is `energyto` because he used it when set the `$username` variable. That's why I gave him this answer. For answering your question: NO, you can see my name in my profile.